# Global variable override by Bootstrap style

Tags: magento2.3.4, variables, global

I have declare **h1 tag font size** in global variable,

app\design\frontend\zero_theme\theme\web\css\source\components_variables.less

```
@h1__font-size: 48px !important;
```

Declare inside the custom less file,

C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\design\frontend\zero_theme\theme\web\css\source\components\common.less

```
h1 {
    font-size:@h1__font-size;    
}
```

When i see website home page, the font override by bootstrap font.

How to apply by global variables to home page?

Answer (score 1):

**Add the below css in your css file**

```
h1 {
    font-size:@h1__font-size !important;    
}
```

after run the below commands,

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: Which css file?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\design\frontend\zero_theme\theme\web\css\source\components\common.less

AS you used the css file ,

Comment: My CMS static block have button, by default bootstrap design applied, how to apply my own design/

Comment: Add the custom css class in your static block button and  add the custom  css in your custom added css class in your css file and also put the your css file link in default_head_blocks.xml file after the bootstrap css link.